# Membership with Microsoft Access

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm doing project in asp.net mvc with Micorsoft Access database and I need to figure out how to make a login system and roles with Microsoft Access.
I have seen some examples on the web:

http://binarywater.com/OleDbASPNETMembershipProvider.html

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=404

I want to understand if they are examples that can be used in asp.nt mvc frmework 1.0 with 3.5.
Because the first link talks about asp.net 2.0 and also create the DataBase aspnetDB.mdb how do I use tables in my db?

You want to be one of your suggestions
Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write your custom MembershipProvider for your access database
or try to find one on the internet...

asp.net versions are different from the mvc versions

mvc framework 1 runs on .net 2.0 runtime....

Comment: Why then when I create a new ASP.NET project with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 mvc1.0, New Project screen, the list cascade. NET Framework 3.5?
what is mean?

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was not aware of this

So my advice to follow the first link as an example?

Thanks again